# Play store Apk ZipAlign Issue

Tags: android, zipalign, android-app-signing

I have zipAlignEnabled flag enables in android studio

And need to build the app for one of the clients who will sign the app and upload it to theirs play store account.

After signing the app, while uploading the play store says apk is not zipaligned 
and when I Zip align again after signing using CMD It gets uploaded in play store.

Do we need to align the app after signing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which zip aligning tool you use

> If you use apksigner, zipalign must only be performed before the APK file has been signed. If you sign your APK using apksigner and make further changes to the APK, its signature is invalidated.
>
> If you use jarsigner, zipalign must only be performed after the APK file has been signed. [Source](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/zipalign.html)

Comment: how do I sign the apk with apksigner using command prompt in windows?

Comment: Next time try reading source... You can find it [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner.html)